# Runtime of this Program

Tags: runtime, asymptotic-complexity

I'm currently in an Intro to Java course and studying for a midterm. I came across this problem:

```
public void wug() {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) {
        for (; j < M; j += 1) {
            if (bump(i, j))
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

N and M are trivial, and are provided somewhere else.

The solution says the runtime if theta(M+N) for the worst case, and theta(N) for the best case. I understand the best case, but I thought the worst case was theta(N*M). Could someone explain why the worst case is theta(M+N)? I'm really shaky on algorithm complexity. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `j` is never reset, so the inner loop iterates at most `M` times. To get `N*M` iterations you'd have to reset the iterator to zero at the start of the loop.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that j isn't initialised in the inner loop so each execution of the inner loop continues from where the previous loop exited.  Think through how that changes the different values that j takes as the program executes.

You'll gain better understanding of this code by setting it up in a debugger and single-stepping through it.  That's because you're seeing what you think the code is doing, not what's actually happening.  Single-stepping the code helps you to focus on the details that make the difference.